# Nome para palavras cuja grafia difere apenas na acentuação, como "ira" e "irá"

Tags: palavra-para-ideia

Duas ou mais palavras são [homógrafas (Michaelis)](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/hom%C3%B3grafo/) se têm a mesma grafia mas significados e pronúncias diferentes, como *ele* pronome e *ele* nome da letra. Mas há palavras que só não têm a mesma grafia por causa dos acentos. Exemplos:

> *ira* e *irá*
>   *solícito* e *solicito*
>   *árbitro* e *arbitro*
>   *polícia* e *policia*

E é claro que não nos poderíamos esquecer do par mais famoso, o *cágado* e o *cagado*. Segundo o site [Norma Culta](https://www.normaculta.com.br/palavras-homografas/), “[a]lguns autores defendem que essas palavras podem ser igualmente consideradas como homógrafas”. Mas existe algum outro **nome que designe exclusivamente palavras cuja grafia é diferente mas apenas na acentuação?**

Comment: chamam-se parónimas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O termo mais próximo que encontrei foi **homógrafo imperfeito**.

---

O [wiktionary](https://pt.wiktionary.org/wiki/par%C3%B4nimo) define como **parônimo** ou **homógrafo imperfeito**:

> vocábulo que se escreve **com as mesmas letras de outro, mas que difere quanto à acentuação gráfica** e ao timbre (ex: fluido e fluído, particípio do verbo fluir; papéis e papeis, do verbo papar); **homógrafo imperfeito**

No mesmo site, há exemplos de homógrafos no [link correspondente ao termo](https://pt.wiktionary.org/wiki/hom%C3%B3grafo):

> diz-se das palavras que têm grafia igual e significação diferente, como por exemplo:
>
> - cará (planta) – cara (rosto)
> - sabia (verbo saber) – sabiá (pássaro) – sábia (feminino de sábio)

Porém, neste caso, não há menção ao termo **imperfeito**.

---

O [Ciber Dúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/homografos-imperfeitos-ou-paronimos-fabricafabrica-podepode/27593) menciona a mesma definição:

> Note-se, no entanto, que o dicionário brasileiro Houaiss esclarece que inclui entre os parónimos «os vocábulos que se escrevem com as mesmas letras mas que diferem quanto à acentuação gráfica e ao timbre (papéis [pl. papel] e papeis [v. papar]), para os quais também se usa a denominação de **homógrafos imperfeitos**»

Esta definição dá a entender que os homógrafos imperfeitos seriam um tipo espefícico de parônimo.

---

[Neste link](http://www.filologia.org.br/ixcnlf/16/16.htm) também há a menção ao termo **homógrafo imperfeito**:

> homógrafos: vocábulos que têm a mesma grafia e pronúncia, mas significados diferentes. Ex.: canto (esquina) e canto (do v. cantar); **vocábulos que se distinguem pela acentuação (homógrafos imperfeitos)**. Ex. fábrica (s. f.) e fabrica (do v. fabricar).

Comment: Creio que *homógrafo imperfeito* serve; parece ser usado por alguns gramáticos para designar exclusivamente este tipo de palavras. Chamá-las pura e simplesmente *homógrafas* parece-me absurdo. De facto o Houaiss diz no verbete *homógrafo* (tás à vontade para adicionar à resosta): "**h[omógrafo] imperfeito** GRAM desgnação adoptada por alguns gramáticos para as palavras que se diferenciam apenas pela acentuação tónica e gráfica (p. ex.: *célebre* [adj,] e *celebre* [fl.celebrar] ʘ USO neste dicionário consideram-se homógrafos e registam-se sob a rubrica HOM apenas os vocábulos que >>

Comment: >> se escrevem com as mesmas letras e que se não diferenciam pela acentuação gráfica; os homógrafos imperfeitos são aqui tratados como parónimos [...]" Mas parónimos inclui também coisas como *coser* e *cozer* e coisas assim. Sim, portanto, homógrafo imperfeito é um tipo de parónimo.

Comment: Poderia haver um "homoliteral" ou "heterodiacrítico" para grafias que possuem as mesmas letras mas diacríticos diferentes. Mas já é forçar muito a barra.

Answer (score 3):

Creio que um bom termo seja "[par mínimo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_pair#Stress)", que denota duas palavras que se distinguem por apenas um fonema (e.g., qualidade vocálica, como em **sé, sê"**) ou por apenas uma característica fonética (e.g., acento, como em **"cágado, cagado"**). Neste caso específico que você pergunta, o termo mais estrito seria "par mínimo por acento" ("minimal pair for stress contrasts"). O artigo da Wikipedia anglófona dá **"esta, está"** como exemplo de par mínimo por acento.

O termo *"homógrafo"* é definido em função da grafia, de tal forma que um par de palavras é homógrafo se a escrita dessas palavras for similar. Porém, "par mínimo" é definido em função da realização fonética da palavra independentemente da forma que é escrita. Portanto, um par de termos escritos de maneiras completamente diferentes, mas que ainda diferem numa só característica fonética, é mínimo mas não é homógrafo.

Um exemplo clássico é o Chinês, cujo sistema de escrita ideográfico atribui um glifo por palavra em vez de compô-la letra-por-letra. Nesta língua não é possível dizer que "馬" (/mǎ/, "cavalo"), "麻" (/má/, "cânhamo"), que diferem apenas pela entonação, formam um par homógrafo, pois são escritos com dois caracteres distintos; mas é possível dizer que formam um par mínimo por contraste de tom.

Comment: adicionando definição de par minimo em outro local -> https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/a-definicao-do-conceito-de-par-minimo/25303

Comment: Interessante. Eu sabia dos pares mínimos na fonética, mas não sabia ou nunca tinha pensado em pares mínimos acentuais, que é na verdade o análogo fonético do que eu procuro. Ou quase, também há palavras como *avó* e *avô*, que se distinguem por acento gráfico e por timbre. Também temos exemplos em português de pares mínimos acentuais que têm diferenças gráficas para lá dos acentos: *caçam* e *cação*.

Comment: De fato, ambos "avó/avô" e "caçam/cação" são pares mínimos, pois diferem em apenas uma característica fonética; mas também possuem diferenças gráficas que a definição de "par mínimo" ignora (por ser um conceito exclusivamente fonético e independente de grafia).

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que sejam palavras homógrafas, escritas iguais (mesmo acentuadas) mas com significado diferente. Está destacado em negrito no texto retirado da internet:

> Repararam certamente que as palavras sobre as quais têm dúvidas
>   começam por homo-, prefixo de origem grega que significa igual,
>   semelhante.
>
> O segundo elemento de cada uma delas é que é diferente: -grafas,
>   também proveniente do grego e que significa escrita; -fonas,
>   igualmente vinda do grego e que significa som: -nimas, da mesma origem
>   e que significa nome.
>
> É fácil, sabendo o significado dos elementos das palavras, chegar ao
>   seu conceito actual.
>
> **Assim, palavras homógrafas são as que se escrevem da mesma maneira,**
>   **mas têm pronúncia e significado diferentes, como fábrica (substantivo)**
>   **e fabrica (verbo) ou pêlo (substantivo) e pelo (contracção da**
>   **preposição por com o artigo definido o).**
>
> As homófonas têm a mesma pronúncia mas escrevem-se de modo diferente,
>   e o seu significado é também diferente. É o caso de conselho (opinião,
>   recomendação) e concelho (divisão administrativa, município), ou aço
>   (metal) e asso (verbo assar).
>
> Finalmente, as homónimas, que têm a mesma forma e o mesmo som, mas
>   significados diferentes: rio (verbo rir) e rio (curso de água), canto
>   (esquina, ponta) e canto (verbo cantar).

Fonte: [Ciberdúvidas da Língua Portuguesa](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/palavras-homografas-homofonas-e-homonimas/1903)

Comment: Obrigado e +1 pela informação e link. Ao que parece a classificação dessas palavras como homógrafa não é consensual, e eu estou interessado num nome exclusivamente para palavras cuja grafia difere mas apenas na acentuação. Editei a pergunta para deixar isso mais claro.

Comment: Talvés um Parônimos? Pensei nisso, mas me parece q a definição é tbm diferente.

Comment: Tens razão, parónimo é diferente, porque também inclui coisas como *coser/cozer comprimento/cumprimento*, etc. Mas inclui também *ira/irá*, etc., excepto talvez para os gramáticos que considerem este último tipo de palavras simplesmente com homógrafos.